# Postfix+Dovecot - How to receive mail for anyuser@anydomain

Tags: email, postfix-mta, dovecot

So the main idea is that I want to do something like this:

1) I send email to anyrandomuser@anyofmydomain.com

2) I receive it with Dovecot, or at least store it in maildir like:
 /vmail/%anydomain/%anyuser

I tried something like this:

cat /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4

relay_domains = *
virtual_mailbox_domains=hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox

virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_minimum_uid = 2222
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:2222
virtual_gid_maps = static:2222
```

cat /etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox

```
@d1.com     d1.com/catchall/
@d2.com     d2.com/catchall/
@d3.com     d3.com/catchall/
```

So that is working pretty well. But its limited to domain-list in /etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox and all mails endup in the same directory. I tried to do some sorting with pcre-map like this:

cat /etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox_pcre

```
/([^\@]+)@([^\s]+)/ ${2}/${1}/
```

But it doesnt work. That's what i get in log:

```
Jan 26 09:41:04 localhost postfix/virtual[5579]: warning: pcre map /etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox_pcre, line 1: regular expression substitution is not allowed: skipping this rule
```

Has anyone done something like that? I'm open to any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving the mail seems to be working for you, the problem appears to be with sorting the mails depending on the recipient domain. The [dovecot sieve extension](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve) might be what you want to use the sorting.

The problem with your `/etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox_pcre` is that the regexp separator (the `/`) is used more than twice, so the regexp engine gets confused.  Try to use some other non-alphanumeric character instead:

```
#([^\@]+)@([^\s]+)# ${2}/${1}/
```

Comment: No it's not that. Regexp-string is absolutely correct. Regular expression substitution is not allowed in this position because of postfix security restrictions. It seems the right way to do that is to process all the mail in dovecot. I think i found a solution. I'll post it later after some tests.